# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: ms-access, search, jdbc, parameters

i have one parameter that i am passing from a JSP using Ajax which is:

```
keyword_name;
```

i have tested to see if their was something in the parameter, their was:

```
apple
```

the code below is my ResultSet:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select keyword_name from keywords                   where keyword_name="+keyword_name+"");
```

and the below is the printing of the result set:

```
while(rs.next()){
buffer=buffer+"<tr><td>"+rs.getString("keyword_name")+"</td></tr>";  
}
```

Full ERROR code:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

Any ideas!!

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be

```
<..> where keyword_name='"+keyword_name+"'"
```